How to move last partition to start?
I want to move partition 3 to be partition 2
I resized- freed space to move 3 into between 1 and 2. But cant

UPDATE: I just did right click on sda3 - copy and pasted on empty unallocated. Apply. And sda2 became empty and windows not working anymore.


Easiest way to do this (not fastest) is to back up all data, delete all partitions and recreate them the way you want, and restore all data, and then reinstall bootloaders.  But I think it's too late for any of that.  Of course, reinstalling from scratch is always an option and frequently faster as long as you don't care about data.
